# Swift: Which direction a UIView is being intersected from?

Tags: ios, swift, cgrectintersectsrect

I am using `CGRectIntersectsRect` to test if `blueView` (being dragged) has intersected with `redView` (stationary). However, I need to know if `redView` was intersected by `blueView` from red's top, bottom, right or left?
Is there a CG method to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do this. You have to write all the complex conditions by comparing the corner points. And you also can enter through corners not just the sides. `CGRectIntersection` returns  the intersection of the two rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I finally used, In case someone else is looking for it. Below line of code test if the intersection is vertical (top & bottom views intersected), where a and b are view.frame for each of the two view intersecting.

`if ((a.maxY > q.maxY) && (b.minY < q.minY)) || ((a.maxY < q.maxY) && (b.minY > q.minY))`

Comment: What is  "q" here. Can you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any CG Method to accomplish this.

The way I'd go about this is using `CGRectIntersectsRect` to check if they intersect at all, then if they do intersect, measure from the center of `redView` to `blueView` which would return the distance between them (X and Y), from that you could possibly tell from which angle the intersection was coming from?

If you wanted a little more accuracy you could measure from `redView` top center, to `blueView` bottom center, and the same for all 4 edges? Then work out which is the closest?

There are multiple ways you could approach this problem but I'm not aware of a 'one method fits all' solution.

**Edit:**

Was still thinking about this, I think the most accurate way would be something like this:

```
let leftDistance = blue.origin.x - (red.origin.x + red.width)
let rightDistance = (blue.origin.x + blue.width) - red.origin.x
let topDistance = blue.origin.y - (red.origin.y + red.height)
let bottomDistance = (blue.origin.y + blue.height) - red.origin.y
```

The the lowest of those distance = coming from the left, right, top or bottom.

(P.s. I might have gotten blue + Red the wrong way around, as well as top and bottom. I'd recommend just having a play around and logging these values while dragging the item)